# Left-aligned equations

Tags: align

My problems are:

1 the equations in the `align` environment should be left-aligned (not centered)

2 there should be no vertical space before the `align` environment

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\underline{Berechnung}
\begin{align*}
    T_{3,-1}(x) &= -4+(-4)\cdot(x-(-1))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-8)\cdot(x-(-1))^2+\frac{1}{6}\cdot(-24)\cdot(x-(-1))^3\\
                &= -4-4\cdot(x+1)-4\cdot(x+1)^2-4\cdot(x+1)^3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To get flush-left equations, pass the option `fleqn` to the `amsmath` package. The remaining amount of whitespace relative to the left margin is controlled by the length parameter `\mathindent`; issue the instruction `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`  if you want absolutely no margin. Personally, I would *not* fiddle with the vertical space settings.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `flalign` environment to get the equations flush with the margin, and the space precedding the `flalign` can be adusted by changing `\abovedisplayskip`:

[image]

An alternate is to use the `aligned` environment which yields similar results.

### Note:

- Note the trailing `&` in the `flalign` environment. This is needed on at least one of the lines.
- The adjustment of the `\abovedisplayskip` was done within a brace group so that subsequent display mode equations are not effected.

---

### Code: `flalign`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\underline{Berechnung}
{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\begin{flalign*}
    T_{3,-1}(x) &= -4+(-4)\cdot(x-(-1))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-8)\cdot(x-(-1))^2+\frac{1}{6}\cdot(-24)\cdot(x-(-1))^3 &\\
                &= -4-4\cdot(x+1)-4\cdot(x+1)^2-4\cdot(x+1)^3
\end{flalign*}%
}%
\end{document}
```

### Code: `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\underline{Berechnung}\par\noindent
$\begin{aligned}
    T_{3,-1}(x) &= -4+(-4)\cdot(x-(-1))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-8)\cdot(x-(-1))^2+\frac{1}{6}\cdot(-24)\cdot(x-(-1))^3 &\\
                &= -4-4\cdot(x+1)-4\cdot(x+1)^2-4\cdot(x+1)^3
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also get using `align*`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{Berechnung}\par\noindent
\begin{align*}
   T_{3,-1}(x) &= -4+(-4)\cdot(x-(-1))+\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-8)\cdot(x-(-1))^2+\frac{1}{6}\cdot(-24)\cdot(x-(-1))^3 & \\
              &= -4-4\cdot(x+1)-4\cdot(x+1)^2-4\cdot(x+1)^3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignstar]

Comment: If you add the `showframe` package you'll see that the equation is not quite flush with the left margin.